# Std::Cin isn't working and says it is an incorrect operator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Principal = 0;
    int RetirementAge = 65;
    int CurrentAge = 0;
    std::cout << "What is your current age?" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> CurrentAge >> std::endl;
    std::cout << CurrentAge << "Is this correct?" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the error that there is no match for 'operator>>'. I'm using codeblocks c++ 11 on codeblocks if that helps.

Comment: 99.99% of the time, when you think "X part of this language isn't working correctly...", It's not the part of the language that isn't working correctly...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sometimes these questions are phrased in such way because of language barrier. In my region, it's common to call out problems in this way and it usually means 'the way I've written std::cin, it's not working'. I hope we can give benefit of doubt here since not everyone is native english speaker on this website :)

Comment: Don't take it as being too critical. It's more a tongue-in-cheek observation reflecting that we have all fallen victim to  momentary bouts of confusion `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this part: `>> std::endl`

`std::endl` is for output streams only, don't use it when reading in `CurrentAge`.

```
std::cin >> CurrentAge;
```